# Mocking file reading/writing via JUnit

Tags: java, junit, mockito, powermockito

How do you mock file reading/writing via JUnit?

Here is my scenario

**MyHandler.java**

```
public abstract class MyHandler {

    private String path = //..path/to/file/here

    public synchronized void writeToFile(String infoText) {
        // Some processing
        // Writing to File Here
        File file = FileUtils.getFile(filepath);
        file.createNewFile();
        // file can't be written, throw FileWriteException
        if (file.canWrite()) {
            FileUtils.writeByteArrayToFile(file, infoText.getBytes(Charsets.UTF_8));
        } else {
            throw new FileWriteException();
        }
    }

    public String readFromFile() {
        // Reading from File here
        String infoText = "";
        File file = new File(path);
        // file can't be read, throw FileReadException
        if (file.canRead()) {
            infoText = FileUtils.readFileToString(file, Charsets.UTF_8);        
        } else {
            throw FileReadException();
        }

        return infoText
    }

}
```

**MyHandlerTest.java**

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({
    MyHandler.class
})
public class MyHandlerTest {

    private static MyHandler handler = null;
    // Some Initialization for JUnit (i.e @Before, @BeforeClass, @After, etc)

    @Test(expected = FileWriteException.class)
    public void writeFileTest() throws Exception {

       handler.writeToFile("Test Write!");

    }

    @Test(expected = FileReadException.class)
    public void readFileTest() throws Exception {

       handler.readFromFile();

    }
}
```

Given above source, Scenario when file is not writable (write permission not allowed) is OK, However, when i try to do scenario wherein `file` is not readable (read permission not allowed). It always read the file, i have already tried to modify the file permission on the test code via below

```
File f = new File("..path/to/file/here");
f.setReadable(false);
```

However, I did some reading, `setReadable()` always returns false (failed) when run on Windows machine.

Is there a way to modify the file permission of the target file programmatically in relation to JUnit?

**Note**

> Target source code to test cannot be modified, meaning
>   `Myhandler.class` is a legacy code which is not to be modified.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of relying on the operating system file permissions, use PowerMock to mock FileUtils.getFile(...) and make it return an instance of File (e.g. anonymous sub class) that returns a specific value for canWrite()/canRead().

[Mocking static methods with Mockito](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21105403/mocking-static-methods-with-mockito)

Comment: Ohh i see, i think i got what you mean, have to try it first though. Thanks

Comment: Note that you should only use PowerMockito as last resort (https://stackoverflow.com/a/30163045/898478). Your case is nowhere near "last resort".

Comment: @m0skit0 "Power Mock should be used in legacy applications where you cannot change the code which has been given to you" I thought this was exactly that case (or in other words, "what is the alternative approach that you're suggesting").

Comment: @Torben I don't see the OP mentioning that `MyHandler` is "legacy code that cannot be changed". You can see my answer for the alternative approach using only Mockito (which btw should also be used only if necessary).

Comment: It must be your browser then, because OP literally says "Myhandler.class is a legacy code which is not to be modified."

Comment: @m0skit0 Its on the note, please do note `MyHandler.class` is only a dummy class since i cannot use the actual source here on stackoverflow (its confidential). That being said, that is the reason i created `MyHandler.class` to show what i wanted to show and convey my point.

Comment: @Torben, thanks, got it working, thanks for the idea.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mockito cannot mock static methods, use a `File` factory instead (or refactor your `FileUtils` to be a factory), then you can mock it and return a mocked `File` instance as well, where you can also mock any `File` methods you want.

So instead of `FileUtils.getFile(filepath)` you will now have something like `FileFactory.getInstance().getFile(filepath)` for example, where you can mock `getFile(String)` method easily.

Comment: Can’t refactor`FileUtils`, its Apache CommonIO library

Comment: Then as I said use your own factory that internally calls FileUtils and then mock the factory methods to return whatever you want.

Comment: @m0skit0 How would you pass the custom factory to MyHandler since it's code can not be modified and it accesses FileUtils.getFile statically?

Comment: @Torben I can't see where OP is saying `MyHandler` cannot be modified.

Comment: It's there where OP says "Target source code to test cannot be modified, meaning  Myhandler.class is a legacy code which is not to be modified."

Answer (score 0):

In jUnit there's a handy rule for scenarios like yours.

```
public class MyHandlerTest {

    @Rule
    // creates a temp folder that will be removed after each test
    public org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder folder = new org.junit.rules.TemporaryFolder();

    private MyHandler handler;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        File file = folder.newFile("myFile.txt");
        // do whatever you need with it - fill with test content and so on.
        handler = new MyHandler(file.getAbsolutePath()); // use the real thing
    }

    // Test whatever behaviour you need with a real file and predefined dataset.
}
```