# How to verify if method of interface is called

Tags: unit-testing, testing, junit, mockito, powermockito

I would like to test if a method from an interface is called. For example, I would like to verify that "map.put(A,B)" is called like in the below code. How would I do this in Junit? Would I need to use Mockito?

```
  public void funcName() {
    Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("VALUE", new Object());
    ...
  }
```

Comment: The ideal solution would be mockito. Here powermock also can be a solution. In this case, you are not separating concerns of logic. That made your function is not easily testable.

Answer (score 0):

If the code was exactly the one you posted, Mockito wouldn't be enough: you would need of PowerMockito.

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MyClass.class})
public class MyTest{
    Map<String, Object> hashMap;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        hashMap = Mockito.spy(new HashMap<>());
        PowerMockito.whenNew(HashMap.class).withAnyArguments().thenReturn((HashMap) hashMap);
    }

    /**
     * Test of doSomething method, of class MyMap.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.funcName();
        Mockito.verify(hashMap).put(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any());
    }
}
```

The use of `PowerMockito` is indeed necessary, when you have testability issues about:

1. Private methods
2. Static methods
3. Final or private class
4. Constructors

But `PowerMockito` is never a *clean* solution: [is always better to avoid using it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162200/why-not-powermock) ; furthemore, using injection leds to better design.

Sometime even less is enough: if your code had been something like this:

```
public void funcName(Map<String, Object> map){
 // something here
  map.put("", obj);
 // other stuff
}
```

It wouldn't have been necessary `PowerMockito`:

```
public class MyTest{
    Map<String, Object> hashMap;

    @Before
    public void setUp() throws Exception {
        hashMap = Mockito.spy(new HashMap<>());
    }

    /**
     * Test of doSomething method, of class MyMap.
     */
    @Test
    public void testDoSomething() {
        MyClass myClass = new MyClass();
        myClass.funcName(hashMap);
        Mockito.verify(hashMap).put(Mockito.anyString(), Mockito.any());
    }
}
```