# How to test IOException case in OkHttp?

Tags: java, mockito, okhttp

I am trying to test my codebase in the event OkHttpClient throws an IOException

**Code under test**

```
    try (var response = okHttpClient.newCall(request).execute()) {
        return response;
    } catch (final IOException e) {
        log.error("IO Error from API", e);
        throw new ApiException(e.getMessage(), e);
    }
```

**Test**

```
@Test
void createCustomer_WhenValidRequestAndIOException_ThenThrowAPIException() throws ZeusServiceException, ZeusClientException {

    //Given
    final OkHttpClient okHttpClientMock = mock(OkHttpClient.class, RETURNS_DEEP_STUBS);
    final OkHttpClient.Builder okHttpBuilderMock = mock(OkHttpClient.Builder.class);
    httpClient = new HttpClient(okHttpClientMock, configuration, objectMapper);

    //When
    when(okHttpClientMock.newBuilder()).thenReturn(okHttpBuilderMock);
    when(okHttpBuilderMock.build()).thenReturn(okHttpClientMock);
    when(okHttpClientMock.newCall(any())).thenThrow(IOException.class);
    final var result = httpClient.createCustomer(request);

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> httpClient.createCustomer(request))
        .isInstanceOf(ApiException.class)
        .hasMessage("IO Error from API");
}
```

I tried to mock the `OkHttpClient` and `Builder` class, however Builder is final, and mockito cannot mock it.

In the constructor of the class under test, you are recommended to create a new instance of OkHttpClient by invoking this

```
        this.okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder().build();
```

I tried to create a wrapper around OkHttpClient but that didn't work either

```
    public class OkHttpClientWrapper extends OkHttpClient {

        private OkHttpClient okHttpClient;

        public OkHttpClientWrapper(final OkHttpClient okHttpClient) {
            this.okHttpClient = okHttpClient;
        }

        @Override
        public OkHttpClient.Builder newBuilder() {
            return new Builder(okHttpClient);
        }
    }
}
```

How can I force okhttpclient to throw an IOException?

Comment: Have you looked into PowerMockito to mock final classes?

Comment: Yea but people say PowerMockito is evil https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162200/why-not-powermock

Comment: maybe creating a `Factory` for `OkHttpClient` and then mocking that `Factory`?

Comment: Have you considered not mocking it at all, but looking up how OkHttp recommends you test this case?

Comment: @tomaytotomato Did you read the answers behind it? It suggests a design issue. However, these are not your types. You can't redesign those types to be more easily tested in a natural manner. There could be other ways to handle the situation (as Louis recommends), but rejecting PowerMockito just because you read on the internet that it's evil, without diving into _why_ it's evil, may lead you to writing more complex test code than actually needed.

Comment: Doesn't change the fact though that PowerMock *is* evil, and that the 2021 answer to unit testing restful endpoints is rather to use something like https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver instead.

Comment: @GhostCat indeed there is a way in MockWebServer to simulate a closed/terminated connection, which covers the test scenario. Please see submitted answer

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the end the best solution was to leverage OkHttp's `MockWebServer`

https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver

Using a scenario where MockWebserver unexpectedly terminates the HTTP connection, causes an IOException scenario

```
@Test
void createCustomer_WhenValidRequestAndServerTerminatesConnection_ThenThrowIOException() throws ZeusServiceException, ZeusClientException {

    //Given
    final CreateCustomerRequest request = CreateCustomerRequest.builder().build();

    //When
    mockWebServer.enqueue(new MockResponse()
        .setBody(new Buffer().write(new byte[4096]))
        .setSocketPolicy(SocketPolicy.DISCONNECT_DURING_RESPONSE_BODY));

    assertThatThrownBy(() -> httpClient.createCustomer(request))
        .isInstanceOf(IOException.class)
        .hasMessage("unexpected end of stream");
}
```

Note: use of AssertJ library in this test

Answer (score 1):

You have a few options:

- Use [Powermock with Mockito](https://github.com/powermock/powermock/wiki/Mockito) to mock the final elements. This will allow you to unit-test all of your code.
- You can use [Wiremock](https://www.infoq.com/articles/Wiremock-testing-mocking-over-wire-stubs/?itm_source=infoq&itm_campaign=user_page&itm_medium=link) or a similar [over-the-wire HTTP mocking tool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_API_simulation_tools) which will allow you to test all of your code in a black-box fashion. All of your code can be [tested this way as a black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black-box_testing).
- Refactor you're code and wrap OkHttp classes and methods in your own classes that can be mocked. This still leaves some code untested.