# Mock ApplicationContext of a class for a Spring based application

Tags: java, spring, applicationcontext

> I have a spring based (no springboot) application inside which I have
> a class as below:

```
 public class MyClass {
    
     private static final ApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);
     
    MyClass (){
     //get the beans from the applicationcontext that myClass is dependent on
    }
    
    //class methods
    
    }
```

> I am trying to unit test MyClass class , but I am unable to mock the
> context that is loaded here -

```
 private static final ApplicationContext context = new 
       AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppContext.class);
```

Please help me here!!!

Comment: You cannot mock a variable which is assigned by creating a new instance by using the `new` keyword. Use a DI framework (like Spring) and inject the instance. Then you can mock it from your tests. Or use something like Powermock

Comment: Hi @user7 Can you elaborate by giving me an example?

Comment: Note: using powermock is not recommended. See [Why not PowerMock](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30162200/why-not-powermock)

Comment: ok I am somehow realizing that I am not following good programming principles :(